# the number closest to the right that is divisible by all its digits

Tags: c++

heres the task
Let's call an integer number elite if it is divisible by every digit of its decimal representation.

Given an integer
x
your program must find the smallest elite number greater than or equal to x
Here's my code, but it still doesnt works with some nums. Plc help me to find the solution.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool isDivisibleByDigits(int number) {
    int originalNumber = number;
    while (number > 0) {
        int digit = number % 10;
        if (digit == 0 || originalNumber % digit != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        number /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
int main() {
    bool flag = false;
    bool flag1 = false;
    ofstream fout("output.txt");
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    string number_str;
    fin >> number_str;
    long long number_int = stoll(number_str);

    for (int i = 0; i < number_str.length(); i++) {
        if (flag1) {
            number_str[i] = '1';
            continue;
        }
        if (number_str[i] == '0') {
            flag1 = true;
            number_str[i] = '1';
        }
    }
    number_int = stoll(number_str);
    while (true) {
        if (isDivisibleByDigits(number_int)) {
            fout << number_int;
            break;
        }
        number_int++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program runs according to the time I need, but does not work for large values.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: What's a "large value"?  10?  100?  1000?

Comment: `isDivisibleByDigits` works with `int` whereas `number_int` is `long long`...

Comment: `int` may be 32 bits when `long long` is 64

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Why posting `ifstream fin("input.txt");` and `long long number_int = stoll(number_str);` if you could simply give an example of the number that breaks your algorithm? The faster someone can copy-paste your code and reproduce the problem, the faster you will get a meaningful answer instead of best-effort guesses.

Comment: Suggestion:  Input number *as a string*.  Convert the string to a number and store (for later).  Iterate through the string, convert digit to number and store into a `std::set`.  Iterate through the set to see if the number is a divisor of the original number.